# How can I make Tail recursion function with OCaml? Syntax advice & explanation needed

Tags: recursion, ocaml, tail

This is a principal code in OCaml, which is for Sigma function with Tail recursion.

```
let sigma_tail_rec term a next b  =
 let rec iter a result = 
   if "A" then "B"
   else iter "C" "D"
 in iter a 0
```

There I don't know how to fill `<A>` to `<D>` and therefore can't compile

Does anyone help me to fill up `<A>` to `... ?

I've tried like this

```
let sigma_tail_rec term a next b  =
 let rec iter a result = 
   if a>b then result+1
   else iter a+1 result+a
 in iter a 0
```

I don't know what "**`in iter a 0`**" syntax means

Answer (score 1):

I can explain `in iter a 0`.

The definition of a recursive local function in OCaml looks like this:

> `let rec` *fun* *arguments* `=` *definition* `in` *expression*

In the *expression* you can call the function *fun*, which is defined by its *definition*.

The skeleton definition of `sigma_tail_rec` is using a local recursive function named `iter` that takes two arguments. And the *expression* (giving the overall value of `sigma_tail_rec`) is `iter a 0`.

It's hard to say more without more information about this assignment. Generally speaking, I'd say you need to call `term` (which probably decides when you've reached the end of the calculation) and `next` (which possibly generates a new value to process). So there is a lot to work out, I'm afraid.